# Print specific property of all objects in an array using join

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following code -

```
var test = [ { id:'1', name: 'a'},  { id:'2' name: 'b'},  { id:'3', name: 'c'}];
alert(test.join(', '));
```

How do I alert `a, b, c`? Right now, I get -

```
[Object, Object, Object]
```

Comment: If you show us your code we can try to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your browser supports ECMAScript 5 (Internet Explorer 8 and lower do not), you can use [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
alert(test.map(function(obj) {
    return obj.name;
}).join(", "));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map each object in your array to the name property that you want to print and use an arrow function for conciseness.

```js
var test = [{id: '1', name: 'a'}, {id: '2', name: 'b'}, {id:'3', name: 'c'}];
alert(test.map(o => o.name).join(", "));
```